# Nexus Issue while trying to Upload Snapshots into Nexus Snapshot repository

Tags: maven, nexus

I am getting the following error in Nexus Snapshot repository while trying to upload snapshots.

```
Downloading: http://maven.teamccp.com/content/repositories/snaphot/apps/home/home-parent/2.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Uploading: http://maven.teamccp.com/content/repositories/snaphot/apps/home/home-parent/2.1-SNAPSHOT/home-parent-2.1-20141113.150651-1.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] Home Parent ............................... FAILURE [  0.742 s]
[INFO] Home Commons .............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Home app .................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Distribution ...................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.860 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2014-11-13T10:06:51-05:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 4M/121M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project home-parent: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not find artifact apps.home:home-parent:pom:2.1-20141113.150651-1 in snapshot (http://maven.teamccp.com/content/repositories
```

I am able to successfuly upload releases. Plz help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The nexus manager has default snapshot repository, which is where your organization will publish internal snapshots. Your deploy cannot find distributionManagement of snapshotRepository, so the error will occur like your question. Therefore, you should set snapshotRepository for deploy your snapshot artifacts. The example is shown below.

pom.xml

```
<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>releases</id>
        <url>http://your-hostname:port/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
    </repository>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>snapshots</id>
        <url>http://your-hostname:port/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>
```

settings.xml

```
<server>
    <id>releases</id>
    <username>your-server-username</username>
    <password>your-server-password</password>
</server>

<server>
    <id>snapshots</id>
    <username>your-server-username</username>
    <password>your-server-password</password>
</server>
```

Answer (score 0):

Each `Uploading:` line should be followed by a corresponding `Uploaded:` line, and since that's missing, my guess is that your upload failed for some reason. I'd check your Nexus logs to see if there's any indication.

I experienced the same problem when my remote repository was out of space (which I found by logging onto the server); I didn't see anything in the Artifactory log.